# Unable to load the data from the fake API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I am unable to load data from the fake API and I keep getting errors.

I have tried it on code sandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-zhukovsky-lbq4n7?file=/src/Users.js

https://fakestoreapi.com/users
This is the fake API ,I am trying to get the data from. Looks like it has nested key -value pairs.

Please help me loop through this format of data.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add more information like what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API seems to work as I get results. What I see is:

`Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {firstname, lastname}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

So `name` is an object that contains `firstname` and `lastname`.

Try using `{user.name.firstname}` instead in the DOM render.